# Rails: Generating a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to generate a hyperlink through combining records from my DB. Here is an example:

```
token_id value is 123456789
user_name value is Peter
brand_id value is 8
```

The token_id+brand_id+user_name should be combined to a new array like unique_id so you'll get this as a result:

```
Unique_id=123456789-8-peter
```

Then I want to put the result inside a clickable URL, like:
      example.com/?campaign=XYZ?Unique_id=<%= unique_id %>

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Read this for starters: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I know that article but it does not help me in that specific case :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what you are actually trying to achieve here but i'll have a guess.

For a start, that's not a valid url: the url must have only one `?` as this tells it when the path ends and the parameters start.  (if you want ? in param values you'll need to url encode it but i don;t think that's what you had in mind).  An example of a valid url would be

```
http://example.com?campaign=XYZ&unique_id=123456789-8-peter
```

which has "/" as the path and then two parameters (campaign and unique_id)

Note that i've used "unique_id" (downcased) as the second param name: by convention param names are all downcased.

To make the link:

```
<% unique_id = [token_id, user_name, brand_id].join("-") %>
<%= link_to home_path(:campaign => "XYZ", :unique_id => unique_id) %>
```

This assumes you've defined a route called "home" which points to "/".  This will need to point to some controller and default action, eg your home controller and "index" action. It also assumes that the variables `token_id`, `user_name` and `brand_id` have been defined somewhere.

Alternately, you might want a url like this, which loads a campaign:

```
 http://example.com/campaigns/XYZ?unique_id=123456789-8-peter
```

Note the path is now "/campaigns/XYZ" rather than just "/".  By convention this would call your CampaignsController's "show" action, passing "XYZ" as params[:id].  you will also get 123456789-8-peter in `params[:unique_id]`.

To generate this link in rails using the link_to helper it might be something like

```
<% unique_id = [token_id, user_name, brand_id].join("-") %>
<%= link_to campaign_path(@campaign, :unique_id => unique_id) %>
```

this expects @campaign to have been defined.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you! You're right, the goal is to have something like this: https://www.example.com/?utm_campaign=123456789-8-peter&utm_source=54321&utm_medium=12345 - I tried to adapt the syntax but it didn't worked out that well.. The "https://www.example.com" btw is also defined inside a record. The db contains different URL's like example.com, example.net, ... 
 I'm sorry for the stupid questions, I'm really new to all those things :(

Comment: That's fine, i don't know what you're asking now though.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to model:

```
def to_param
  [token_id, brand_id, user_name.parameterize].join("-")
end
```

More information you can find here: [Friendly URLs](https://gist.github.com/cdmwebs/1209732)